# Error C2893 Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2015

I use std::thread in my C++ class in my Visual Studio 2015 project.

```
class BaggageSoln {
        void mainProcess();
        // Threading functions
        void run();
        void startZED();        
        void closeZED();
private:
        std::thread zed_callback;

}

void BaggageSoln::startZED()
{
    // Start the thread for grabbing ZED data
    has_data = false;
    zed_callback = std::thread(&BaggageSoln::run);

    //Wait for data to be grabbed
    while (!has_data)
        sleep_ms(1);
}

void BaggageSoln::mainProcess() {}
void BaggageSoln::run() {}
void BaggageSoln::closeZED(){}
```

Error is happening at xthread file at line 238.
What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&BaggageSoln::run` requires an instance to be called, make it `static` or provide an instance.

```
zed_callback = std::thread(&BaggageSoln::run, this);
```